# A simple representation of smooth function

Tags: calculus

Let $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a smooth real-valued function, and $f$ satisfys $$f(\mathbf{0})=0,\ {\partial f\over\partial x_i}(\mathbf{0})=0, \forall\ 1\leq i\leq n.$$
Then acoording to the **first-order Taylor formula with a integral reminder**, there exist smooth real-valued functions $g_1,\cdots,g_n\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n),$ such that $$g_i(\mathbf{0})=0, \forall\ 1\leq i\leq n,\mbox{ and} $$$$f(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^n g_i(\mathbf{x})\cdot x_i,\ \forall\ \mathbf{x}=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n.$$ 
**Question:** Are there  other methods of proving the existence of $g_i,$ especially a non-constructive proof ?  Any help would be appreciated.